# While using tinyvec I get "field does not implement `Copy`" even though both ArrayVec and Item impl Copy

Tags: rust

Anyone know what's going on here? Why am I getting

> this field does not implement `Copy`

```
use tinyvec::ArrayVec;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Item {
    num: i32
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Test {
    nums: ArrayVec<[Item; 20]>
}

fn main() {

    let mut x = Test {
        nums: ArrayVec::new()
    };

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Copy` is implemented for `ArrayVec`](https://docs.rs/tinyvec/1.3.1/tinyvec/struct.ArrayVec.html#impl-Copy) with the following constraints:

```
impl<A> Copy for ArrayVec<A> where
    A: Array + Copy,
    A::Item: Copy,
{}
```

In this case, `A` is an `[Item; 20]`, so it implements `Copy`. However, `[Item; 20]` *does not* satisfy the constraints to implement [`Array`](https://docs.rs/tinyvec/1.3.1/tinyvec/trait.Array.html).

```
impl<T: Default> Array for [T; 20] {
  // ^^^^^^^^^^
```

For `[Item; 20]` to be an `Array`, `Item` needs to implement `Default`.